# How to prevent a user from just typing spaces in a textarea

Tags: php, html

I have seen many other questions which mostly ask how to prevent spaces from being entered in the whole textarea, but I am wondering how I can check if the textarea just contains spaces?

For example, here is my textarea:

```
<textarea id='textarea' name='msg' rows='2' maxlength='255' cols='80' placeholder=' Share a thought...'></textarea>
```

I can easily check if the above is empty by doing:

```
$post_msg = htmlentities(strip_tags(@$_POST['msg']));
$post_msg=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$post_msg);
if ($post_msg != "") {
  // do this
}
```

But, if a user enters just space characters in, then the field is obviously not empty no more, invalidating the above check. How can I check if the user has entered space characters?

A message can start off with space characters, but it cannot only be space chars.

Comment: `empty` is a better option than checking if it's not an empty string. http://php.net/empty

Comment: trim, ltrim, rtrim are all functions that you can use to remove spaces.  trim will remove white spaces from the beginning and end of a string, ltrim removes from left and rtrim removes from right.

Comment: Trim the value, then check if it's empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments are mentioning, you should look at the [TRIM function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) for PHP and/or JavaScript.

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will strip these characters:
>
> - " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> - "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> - "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> - "\r" (ASCII 13> (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> - "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> - "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

To implement I like to Trim pretty early on, so I'd probably do it with `htmlentities()` line

```
$post_msg = htmlentities(trim(strip_tags(@$_POST['msg'])));
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you could use this, this will not only check for spaces but also any other form of blank space:

```
$post_msg = htmlentities(strip_tags(@$_POST['msg']));
$post_msg=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$post_msg);
$post_msg_check=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $post_msg);
if ($post_msg_check == "") {
  // User's entry is blank $post_msg is the user's entry
} else {
  // User's entry is not blank $post_msg is the user's entry
}
```

Comment: This will remove all spaces, not just extra spaces.

Comment: The preg_replace is meerly for checking the string, I will edit my answer to make that more clear, and htmlentities is something he bad in his previous code so it has to be there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript function **trim()** it removes the white spaces and check if the user enter a empty string

```
var str =  document.getElementById("id").value;
if(str.trim() == '') {

alert("error");
}
```

Comment: Don't rely on the client. Do it on the server.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I think it should be done on both client & server. Server for your own sanity & protection. Client for the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You could `trim` your string before checking if it is empty

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
$trimmed = trim($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer

```
$post_msg = htmlentities(strip_tags(@$_POST['msg']));
$post_msg=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$post_msg);
$post_msg_check_space=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $post_msg);
if ($post_msg_check_space==""){
   //there's only space
}else{
   //there's things other than space, use $post_msg
}
```

You can also check with javascript before sending and checking in php with trim:

```
var string =  document.getElementById("id").value;
var string_check_space = string.trim();
if (string_check_space !=''){
   getElementById("buttonSubmit")[0].submit();
}
```